# Hiding elements when cart is empty in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopping-cart

In order to hide a line of text on an empty cart I tried

`{% if cart.item_count > 0 %} your html here {% endif %}`

This seems to work because it does when the cart starts out empty. But I assume the page is not refreshing during add to cart (That seems to be the case if a theme using ajax add to cart functionality.)

I wonder what I need to do in order to make it work anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, liquid is a server-side rendered language. There is nothing you can do in liquid to update the page after an ajax call.

The only way is Javascript.
When you do the ajax call, your should be calling the `cart.js` or `add.js` or `update.js` endpoints, in these cases you receive an object with an array: `items`.

You need to check (in Javascript) if `responseData.items.length>0` to see if there are items in the cart.

To make an example, this is your `.liquid`.

```
{% if cart.item_count > 0 %} 
  <div id="#mycart">...</div>
{% endif %}
```

Now in your javascript code, you might have something like

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/add.js',
        data: payload,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
             if (data["item_count"] === 0) {
                 $("#mycart").hide();
             }else{
                 $("#mycart").show();
             }

        },
        error: function () {
           handleError();
        }
    });
```

I'm using jQuery, but is just to give you the idea.

Comment: Okay so I would be able to find this in theme.js right? I'm still lost I guess but I also believe this isnt hard once I understood where to find what I need to edit and how to edit it

Comment: You are not saying which theme you're using and honeslty I'm not an expert of all the themes out there. But search for `cart.js`, `update.js`, `add.js` or `change.js` and you should find where the cart is updated.

Comment: Of course. :-) I'm also sorry for asking like an idiot, but sadly I'm missing a deeper understanding when it comes to js. In terms of theme I have a custom edited version of Prestige by Maestrooo

Look at what I found: https://prnt.sc/e1HTRMVz8790

Comment: Yes @ChrisGrundmann that could be the point. Indeed there is also the variable `item_count` (check the API here https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#post-locale-cart-update-js) and you can use that to hide your element. I'm adding an example in the answer to how hide the div in JS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and effort!

Okay I tried to add this into my codes :-D Funny thing is that it will hide away the cart and search icon inside my shop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOsKh.png

I guess I need to take a break :-D


I assume I apply it correctly in general but I guess I struggle with the correct position of the .hide /.show javascript. 

Alt least thats my guess here.

Comment: To select a class you need a `.`. So if the div has class "a b c d" to select it you need to do `$(".a.b.c.d").show()`

Comment: Sadly no change there. I really assume I'm missing something fundamental. Cause the shop hides elements but not the one I want to hide but I assume its impossible for you as well to help from the outside

Comment: @ChrisGrundmann best I can do is make you an example on codepen https://codepen.io/0xFAB10/pen/vYdvQEQ

Comment: Thanks for the example. I understand how this is working in general but I guess the 2 values I have marked yellow in the image https://prnt.sc/uHxKBWMyd9hj just aren't correct. So the function itself works, but I'm not addressing the correct element for the ==0 part so the element won't hide since I'm not actually measure the amount of items in the cart... you know what I mean? hmhmhm